# anaconda packages installed but not found

Tags: import, conda

I have a new macbook air running yosemite and I have installed Anaconda.

I want to practise on making GUIs with either wxpython.

When I  run " conda list" wxpython is there, but when I import it I get "No module named wxpython" .

Any ideas how to fix this? Anaconda is added  to my path in the bash_profile.

Regards

Comment: Perhaps you are not running the import command in the Anaconda Python.  What happens when you do `which python`?

Comment: Hello!

It says "~/anaconda/bin/python".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20Learn%20wxPython) it looks like the correct way to import this package is `import wx`.  Try that.

It's possible you might run into a cairo error like this:
`ImportError: /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_ft_font_options_substitute`.  I was able to get around this by installing the cairo package via `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/pmuller cairo`.